# Escape XML from database for output

Tags: php, html, xml, zend-framework, encoding

I'm trying to create a zend_form using XML, the passed XML includes all the tags so I can't use `htmlspecialchars()` because the tag < > would be encoded which I dont want.  Is there any easy way to encode just elements that are text values of the tags (the content between tags)?

```
$xml = sprintf('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><form><localhost><formmanager><formpage><elements>%s</elements></formpage></formmanager></localhost></form>',
                                $r['form_template']);
$config = new Zend_Config_Xml($xml, 'localhost');
$form = new Zend_Form($config->formmanager->$formName);
```

An extract of the xml saved on the DB :

```
<questionTechnicalServices>
<type>MultiCheckbox</type>
<options>
<class>rule2 standard basic2 starter business spotlight</class>
<label>Technical Services</label>
<multioptions>
<item-ContractLaboratoryandtestingServices>Contract Laboratory and testing Services</item-ContractLaboratoryandtestingServices>
<item-ContractRDDesignandEngineering>Contract R&D, Design and Engineering</item-ContractRDDesignandEngineering>
<item-ContractSterilization>Contract Sterilization</item-ContractSterilization>
<item-CoilingRespoolingWinding>Coiling/Respooling/Winding</item-CoilingRespoolingWinding>
<item-OthersTechnicalServices>Others</item-OthersTechnicalServices>
</multioptions>
</options>
</questionTechnicalServices>
```

The & from R&D, needs to be changed to `&amp;` as would any > or < etc.

Regards,

Comment: The XML saved in the DB is invalid. The element values should be escaped before they are stored. Not doing that causes exactly the problem you have now. However, you may be able to correct it by loading it into [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) as HTML and saving it back to a string. Although since it is already invalid, there is no guarantee that any parser will do what you want it to.

Comment: I've always been told/taught that data in the database should always be raw and only to encode for the output source. Is there a different rule for storing xml, or is storing the tags and data not common?

Comment: If the data in the database is XML, it should be valid XML. It's not a case of `data in the database should always be raw` - that is true, but more importantly data in the database should be *valid*. XML *is* the raw data here, but it is also a container for a subset of raw data. If that XML is invalid, the next link in the chain won't be able to understand it (as you have no doubt discovered).

Comment: Ok this should be fine now. If you want to leave a answer ill give you a tick. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML saved in the DB is invalid. The element values should be escaped before they are stored. Not doing that causes exactly the problem you have now.

However, you may be able to correct it by loading it into [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) as HTML and saving it back to a string. Although since it is already invalid, there is no guarantee that any parser will do what you want it to.